# Constraints for my view are not working. How can I get my label text to stay within the guidelines?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: The word discussion is going past the constraints. I]

I want the word discussion to be inside this view. I'm not sure why it isn't pushing to the next line if it can not fit.

```
checkLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: -48).isActive = true
checkLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
checkLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
checkLabel.numberOfLines = 0
checkLabel.textAlignment = .left
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your label's rightmost side is allowed to trail off by 15 points because of your right anchor constraint. Your right anchor constraint should have a constant of -15, not 15, in order to inset your label correctly:

```
checkLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
```

You could also just reverse the order of the anchors, too, instead of changing the sign of the constant:

```
rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
```

Comment: The first method worked for me, thank you. I'm just curious what you mean by switching the order in the second method

Comment: Let's call `checkLabel.rightAnchor` r0 and `self.rightAnchor` r1. Your constraint's equation in your question was basically: "r0 = r1 + 15". My first method says to just change the sign of the constant, like this: "r0 = r1 - 15". My second method is just a reordering of the terms in that equation: "r1 = r0 + 15". Also, take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html